Having difficulty in importing CSS stylesheet into my backstage plugin
I have a backstage plugin, and I am unable to import a CSS stylesheet in one of the components.
This is my folder structure:

CreateComponent.tsx
import React from 'react'; 
import './styles.css';

export const CreateComponent = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Hello, World</h1>
        </div>
    );
}

styles.css
h1 {
    color: red;
}

The exact same code works within a different plugin, but it doesn't work here. I have tried deleting the plugin and creating a new one too. Any help is appreciated, thanks!
